# Javascript: Pass Hash Key as Parameter

Tags: javascript

I have a hash called 'tag' with several keys, including width, height, x, and y. I also have this function:

```
function invertCoordinates(measure, coordinate){
    tag.measure = tag.measure * -1;
    tag.coordinate = tag.coordinate - tag.measure;
}
```

In which I want to pass tag's keys:

```
invertCoordinates(width, x);
```

or

```
invertCoordinates(height, y);
```

Unfortunately, I can't pass keys in this manner. Is there some other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you do:

```
function invertCoordinates(measure, coordinate){
    tag[measure] = tag[measure] * -1;
    tag[coordinate] = tag[coordinate] - tag[measure];
}
```

where measure and coordinate are strings? For instance:

```
invertCoordinates("width", "x");
```

Comment: You should note that he'll need to pass in `measure` and `coordinate` as strings: `'width'`, `'x'`, `'y'`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use the array-access notation (`tag[measure]`) and pass the keys as strings: `invertCoordinates('width', 'x')`

Comment: Your answer works perfectly, but Matt responded simultaneously with a slightly more explicit example. I'm giving you an upvote but giving him the check. Thanks anyway!

Comment: No worries, I'm trying to help rather than collect reputation. I don't really give a … about that.